# BigBlueButton audio stuck at echo test

Tags: webrtc, html5-audio, bigbluebutton

I successfully installed BigBlueButton. There are no errors in the terminal output as well. When accessing the demo html5client, whiteboard, poll etc are working. However, the audio option is stuck at echo testing and show a timeout with `1006` error code. I have SSL enabled and working fine as well.

**My browser console output is below:**

```
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:919678135@video.somesite.co SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 1n1efh9eohaf.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5324934
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:919678135@video.somesite.co>
From: "w_sovik6bkaxev_3-bbbID-safwan" <sip:w_sovik6bkaxev_3-bbbID-safwan@video.somesite.co>;tag=h2nok8abpf
Call-ID: duvvdruvnusg9plutmb4
CSeq: 9420 INVITE
Contact: <sip:68b55qmr@1n1efh9eohaf.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,REFER
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: BigBlueButton
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 1795

v=0
o=- 3589643919046748830 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS RebgqLQCswcUs4ScXPJ80b2tBsr9DMhFdM3k
a=group:BUNDLE audio
m=audio 27918 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 103.94.139.173
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=sendrecv
a=ice-ufrag:+lmV
a=ice-pwd:RlEpQu8rx1eHH+3sBsFbXN7q
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D9:C2:60:2B:63:3F:9B:B6:55:08:A7:4F:27:68:C7:64:13:9A:E7:B2:92:55:7B:7B:63:06:D3:A0:45:52:CB:4D
a=candidate:1516508954 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.106 49826 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:350743530 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.106 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3677098414 1 udp 1686052607 103.94.139.173 27918 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.106 rport 49826 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ssrc:393152659 cname:AnxncDEBB143RIk/
a=ssrc:393152659 msid:RebgqLQCswcUs4ScXPJ80b2tBsr9DMhFdM3k 90032642-1086-4a34-b9c8-a9e9649183a8
a=ssrc:393152659 mslabel:RebgqLQCswcUs4ScXPJ80b2tBsr9DMhFdM3k
a=ssrc:393152659 label:90032642-1086-4a34-b9c8-a9e9649183a8
a=rtcp-mux


sip.js?v=870:1272 SIP.EventEmitter#off is deprecated and may be removed in future SIP.js versions.
Please use removeListener or removeAllListeners instead.
See here for more details:
http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener
off @ sip.js?v=870:1272
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
exitAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
d @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
l @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setupEventHandlers @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
doCall @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
handleGoToEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
validateDisabled @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
internalClickHandler @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
s @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
h @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
m @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
O @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
N @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
C @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
R @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
Ln @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
ns @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
We @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
zn @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
os @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
In @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.inviteclientcontext | terminating Session
228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 [03:35:34:0952] ERROR: clientLogger: Audio error - errorCode=1006, cause=Call timed out on start after 20s https://video.somesite.co/html5client/228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121:1100897
sip.js?v=870:1272 SIP.EventEmitter#off is deprecated and may be removed in future SIP.js versions.
Please use removeListener or removeAllListeners instead.
See here for more details:
http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener
off @ sip.js?v=870:1272
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
exitAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setupEventHandlers @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
doCall @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
handleGoToEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
validateDisabled @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
internalClickHandler @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
s @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
h @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
m @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
O @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
N @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
C @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
R @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
Ln @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
ns @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
We @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
zn @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
os @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
In @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.inviteclientcontext | terminating Session
sip.js?v=870:5031 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'remote_target' of null
    at InviteClientContext.sendRequest (sip.js?v=870:5031)
    at InviteClientContext.bye (sip.js?v=870:4906)
    at r (228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121)
    at 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at T.exitAudio (228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121)
    at 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
sendRequest @ sip.js?v=870:5031
bye @ sip.js?v=870:4906
r @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
exitAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
setupEventHandlers @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
doCall @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
handleGoToEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
validateDisabled @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
internalClickHandler @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
s @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
h @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
m @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
O @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
N @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
C @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
R @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
Ln @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
ns @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
We @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
zn @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
os @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
In @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.transaction.ict | Timer B expired for INVITE client transaction z9hG4bK5324934
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.inviteclientcontext | closing INVITE session duvvdruvnusg9plutmb4qp7uju617n
sip.js?v=870:2900 Thu Apr 02 2020 03:35:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | closing PeerConnection
sip.js?v=870:1272 SIP.EventEmitter#off is deprecated and may be removed in future SIP.js versions.
Please use removeListener or removeAllListeners instead.
See here for more details:
http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener
off @ sip.js?v=870:1272
x @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
EventEmitter.emit @ sip.js?v=870:115
terminated @ sip.js?v=870:5653
onRequestTimeout @ sip.js?v=870:6943
onRequestTimeout @ sip.js?v=870:3709
InviteClientTransaction.timer_B @ sip.js?v=870:7744
setTimeout (async)
Timers.<computed> @ sip.js?v=870:7516
InviteClientTransaction.send @ sip.js?v=870:7707
send @ sip.js?v=870:3698
ClientContext.send @ sip.js?v=870:452
onSuccess @ sip.js?v=870:6489
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
invite @ sip.js?v=870:6481
afterConnected @ sip.js?v=870:8842
UA.invite @ sip.js?v=870:8861
inviteUserAgent @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
doCall @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinAudio @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1
Promise.then (async)
n.then @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:21
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
joinEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
handleGoToEchoTest @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
validateDisabled @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
internalClickHandler @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121
s @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
h @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
m @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
O @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
N @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
C @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
R @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
Ln @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
ns @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
We @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
zn @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
(anonymous) @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
os @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
In @ 228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 [03:35:47:0280] ERROR: clientLogger: Audio call terminated. cause=Request Timeout InviteClientContext.x (https://video.somesite.co/html5client/228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121:1129909)
228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 [03:35:47:0294]  INFO: clientLogger: Absorbing a redundant callback message. T.l [as callback] (https://video.somesite.co/html5client/228c0528110c687efe22ece78b851a4d30a9b3dd.js?meteor_js_resource=true:121:1124518)
```

Out of `bbb-conf --status`

```
nginx —————————————————► [✔ - active]
freeswitch ————————————► [✔ - active]
redis-server ——————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-apps-akka —————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-transcode-akka ————► [✔ - active]
bbb-fsesl-akka ————————► [✔ - active]
red5 ——————————————————► [✔ - active]
tomcat7 ———————————————► [✔ - active]
mongod ————————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-html5 —————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-webrtc-sfu ————————► [✔ - active]
kurento-media-server ——► [✔ - active]
etherpad ——————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-web ———————————————► [✔ - active]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. Worked beautifully for me.

https://chadpilkey.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/fixing-your-bigbluebutton-audo-issue/

Basically the solution is to run:
sudo bbb-conf --clean
sudo bbb-conf --check
sudo bbb-conf --clean

Answer (score 0):

In my instance,

```sh
sudo bbb-conf --setip domainname.com
```

solved it.